# In batch, how can i pass the file path of the element i right clicked as an argument?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, arguments, parameter-passing

I've added a context menu for right clicking images with the .png file extension using regedit, which currently has the 'command key':

```
"C:\Application\ConvertImageToWallpaper.bat" "hello"
```

This bat file contains the following code:

```
start cmd /k C:\Application\test1.py %1
```

And again, this python file simply prints the given batch argument:

```
import sys
print("argument:",sys.argv[1])
```

How can i change my command key in reg edit to pass the path of the right clicked file instead of "hello"?

Comment: Ironically it is %1 in the registry setting. https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8729

Comment: Replace `"hello"` by `"%1"`

Comment: @Squashman man thats frustrating, i thought i had tried all the variations. If you post it as answer i'll approve it. thank you!

Comment: @ThomasB. Actually it is a duplicate question. SST and I both answered a similar question the other day here on StackOverFlow. I just need to find the question. I started that thread on DosTips after the question I answered here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @sst and @Squashman suggest to you in the comments :

You should write in the registry this command key :

```
"C:\Application\ConvertImageToWallpaper.bat" "%1"
```